# How do I allow a user to only view their user documents and nothing else?

Tags: permissions, folder

So in our sharepoint we have some company folders and user folders so that each user has their own place to store their files. We have a new user starting soon and I want them to only have access to their own documents folder and not be able to access any other folders on sharepoint?

Could you please walk me through how I would go about doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: One Drive for Business is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

Your SharePoint administrator or whoever who has access could create a folder inside the document library, and set the permission to that folder to a particular user, and remove everyone aside from that user.

1. Go to your target document library
2. Create New Folder (available through the toolbar), and set the name
3. Check that folder
   [image]
4. On the toolbar, click the Shared with icon
   [image]
5. Click Advanced
   [image]
6. Click Break Inheritance to apply special permission to the folder (in this case, 1 user for 1 folder)
   [image]
7. Click Grant Permission and add the user for that folder. You could also remove everyone who should not be accessing that folder.
   [image]

Of course if you do not want that user to view other documents, you need to revoke his / him permissions from other document library.